# How to create dictionary for data from Excel sheet to display in Console application (c#)

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary

The idea of the project I'm implementing is to get some data from an excel sheet as seen below:
[column : FileName/docName and row:cells B-J (fieldType) are two things used to create a key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKKep.png) 
The docName and Fieldtype are concatenated in the format (docName/fieldType) to give me a key which I store in a dictionary.
I need to store the value from the corresponding cell from the excel sheet that matches to the key with the condition that its not null.

```
public class ReadingExcel
{
    #region Members

    int col = 1;
    int row = 1;
    int limit = 0;
    int valLimit = 1;
    int colLimit = 0;
    int rowLimit = 0;
    int totalColumns;
    int totalRows;
    string resultRowTemp = string.Empty;
    string result = string.Empty;
    StringBuilder concatValue = new StringBuilder();
    Application excelApp = new Application();
    Workbook ExtractionBook;
    Worksheet Sheet;
    Range dataRange;
    List<string> docName = new List<string>();
    List<string> fieldType = new List<string>();
    List<string> rowFieldValues = new List<String>();
    List<string> excelData = new List<String>();
    List<string> concatKey = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string,List<string>> docFieldDictionary = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public void ExtractKeys(string docPath, string sheetName, string key)
    {

        ExtractionBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(docPath);
        Sheet = (Worksheet)ExtractionBook.Sheets[sheetName];
        dataRange = (Range)Sheet.Cells;
        totalColumns = Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        totalRows = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

        //To get the docName alone 
        for (row = 2; row <= totalRows; row++)
        {
            dataRange = (Range)Sheet.Cells[row, col];
            result = (string)dataRange.Value2;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                docName.Add(result);

            }
        }

        //To get the fields alone     
        for (col = 1; col <= totalColumns; col++)
        {
            dataRange = (Range)Sheet.Cells[col];
            result = (string)dataRange.Value2;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                fieldType.Add(result);
            }
        }

        //To create the Dictionary Keys
        for (limit = 0; limit < docName.Count; limit++)
        {
            for (valLimit = 1; valLimit < fieldType.Count; valLimit++)
            {

                concatValue = concatValue.Append(docName[limit]).Append("/").Append(fieldType[valLimit]);
                result = concatValue.ToString();
                concatKey.Add(result);
                concatValue.Clear();

            }

        }
```

I am clueless on how to proceed further to add the key and how to obtain the corresponding value from the excel sheet.

The next step I tried is to store all the fieldType values for a corresponding docName in rowFieldValues list.

```
      //To read the entire excel sheet
            for (row = 2; row <= totalRows; row++)
            {
                for (col = 1; col <= totalColumns; col++)
                {
                    dataRange = (Range)Sheet.Cells[row, col];
                    result = (string)dataRange.Value2;
                    excelData.Add(result);               
                }
            }
            // To fetch and store data for each docName
            for ( rowLimit = 0; rowLimit < excelData.Count; rowLimit++)
            {
                for (limit = 0; limit < docName.Count; limit++)
                {
                    if (docName[limit] == excelData[rowLimit])
                    {
                        for (colLimit = 0; colLimit < fieldType.Count; colLimit++)
                        {
                            rowFieldValues.Add(excelData[colLimit]);
                            docFieldDictionary.Add(docName[limit], rowFieldValues);
                        }
                    }
                }       
            }
```

I've got three problems:

1.rowFieldValues list returns the same data for all the docNames.

2.I get the error [error msg saying: same dicitonary key is already added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzKTf.png)

3.I am not able to iterate to the next docName in the nested for loops once all the rowFieldValues for one docName is added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really workout what your particular issue is based on the code that you posted.  But I would recommend rethinking your approach.

If I was trying to get data from an excel spreadsheet with a known format. I would design a class that encapsulates that data.

e.g.

```
public class DocDetails
{
    public string B { get; set; }
    ...
    public string J { get; set; }
}
```

Note: variables B - J are examples only .. use something descriptive of the actual property.

Then your dictionary would be a dictionary of DocDetails, and the key of the dictionary is simply the docName.

This would almost definitely make the dictionary easier to use in your C# application because you wont have to build Keys to get values.  Also you can easily get a list of doc names by getting the KeyList from the dictionary.

To populate the dictionary, you simply crawl over each row where the docName column is set, and populate a new DocDetails object based on the other columns.

Comment: I agree I have to restructure my code, I have a  requirement wherein at some point I need to get only one  particular fieldType value for that particular docName hence the concatenated key approach. I will embed this in your suggested strategy and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Another thing to add on is that the excel sheet will not be in a standard format.It depends on what kind of Document information we are saving.for eg: mortgage,lease,rent based docs etc

Comment: Do you mean different columns will be used depending on the kind of document? Or do you mean the same columns are used for different types of data depending on the document type?

Comment: I mean different columns will be used depending on the kind of document. for eg: one document may have DOB and another document type may not.

Comment: I dont have enough rep to comment on your original question, but I think I can see some bugs in your application.  In the method ExtractKeys, you never explicitly set the 'col' variable to 1. If this gets called multiple times then the col could be any value (most likely the highest used column value)

Comment: If  you mean to get the docNames alone loop ,I tried to keep col =1 constant so that I could read only the first column (I think I have declared it initially in the #region Members)